# C++: Binary Heap

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ implementation of a Binary Heap, but I'm having some issues getting started. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class binaryHeap {

public:

    // Constructor
    binaryHeap(int _capacity)
    {
        // initializes the binary heap with a capacity, size, and space in memory
        _size = 0;
        _n = ceil(pow(2, log10(_capacity)/log10(2)));
        _heap = new int[_n];
    }

    ~binaryHeap(void)
    {
        delete[] _heap;
    }

/* Omitted: insert, remove, size, capacity functions
   Not necessary to the issue I'm having */

private:

    int _size;
    int _capacity;
    int _n;
    int *_heap;
};
```

In the main.cpp file, when I write the following line:

```
struct BinaryHeap heap(10);
```

I get the error: *Variable has incomplete type 'struct BinaryHeap'*. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: If you're doing C++ you might want to use `std::vector` instead of a C-style array. Also is it `binaryHeap` or `BinaryHeap`? The latter is more conventional C++.

Comment: Why are you using `struct BinaryHeap heap(10);`? why not just using `BinaryHeap heap(10);`? secondly, there is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a typo problem. Your binary heap class is `binaryHeap`, while in your `main` function, you are saying `struct BinaryHeap heap(10);`, which in the compiler's POV is a completely different type.

Comment: Wow, it would be that simple, haha. Thanks!